# WooCommerce Empty Cart if User Go to Page or Site Other than Current Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm not sure if this is right question to ask but still, I did not find any solutions for it. I am trying to create a method where when user go to page/site other than the current Checkout page, user's cart will automatically emptied. I wonder if this is possible because I have changed the purchase flow of my custom E-shop. I have tried search on the Internet and try many methods, but it doesn't seem to work. I am currently having a hard time on understanding how WooCommerce's hooks & functions work.

Now, let me tell you guys how my code works from the beginning:-

These are the code for the page that display the whole available product. As you can see, when user wanted to buy a product, they will click the Buy button and my E-shop will automatically add that product into the cart.

```
<?php
// Querying of product information retrieval
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'menu_order', 'order' =>'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

// Display each retrieved product
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
$loop->the_post();

// WooCommerce global product variable
global $product;
global $woocommerce;


the_title();
the_excerpt();
echo $product->get_price_html();
$id = $product->id;
?>

/**** Select the product & automatically add to cart ****/
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="' . $id . '"]'); ?>"><button type="button"> BUY</button></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // After the loop ended, quit the custom loop and reset back the main loop 
?>
```

When my E-shop have completed the 'add to cart' process, the user will be redirected to the Checkout Page. The function for it is as below.

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
global $woocommerce;
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
return $checkout_url;
}
```

Basically what I am trying to tell is, the user will directly redirected to the Checkout page after they click to buy that product. This method skipped the Single Product page & Add to Cart page.

But right now, I need help on determining the right method **if user get out of that page or log-out, the cart will be automatically empty**. Is it possible? If not, sorry for my lack of knowledge.

I have been trying the code below as it is the closest what I want it to do. Close, but not working.

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( !is_page('93') ) { 
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
```

With the above function, whenever I tried to go back to home page, or go to other link and click buy again, the cart just keep adding. This thing is making me losing my mind. I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Hi Kaydarin. Did you ever find a solution for this? I need to do the same thing.

Comment: @inspirednz pls try my solution

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty dangerous path to go down since users that open multiple tabs of your website will be affected by the clear cart code when any other tabs become active.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress conditional dont work when `init` (its too early to use `is_page('93')`) . so use something that dont relies on WordPress conditionals:

get the page url of `is_page('93')` lets say : www.domain.name/checkout

then use this code in functions.php:

```
/*empty cart if user come to homepage*/
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !=== '**www.domain.name/checkout**') { 
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
 }
}
```